# Alternating colors of Rows with specific TR class

Tags: css

How can I alternate the colors of rows in a table that have a `tr` with a specific class?

In my example table below, I would like to have rows that alternate between shades of green, and rows between different shades of orange.

I tried various CSS selectors to no avail.
I would like to avoid doing this in jQuery.

```css
th {
  height: 30px;
}

tr.green:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f1f8e9;
}

tr.green:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f8e9;
}

tr.orange:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff8e1;
}

tr.orange:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffecb3;
}
```

```html
<table data-vertable="ver2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>no class</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="green">
      <th>green</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <th>green</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="orange">
      <th>orange</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="orange">
      <th>orange</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Example of the kind of alternating I am talking about:
[image]

Comment: Your current CSS didn't match your DOM structure at all, I've taken the liberty of fixing it as seemed reasonable to match your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `.green` is a class of `tr` so you should not write it like `.green tr` but you can simply go with `.green` secondly change the `nth` selector to `nth-child` . Check the snippet for details

```css
.green:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}
.green:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.orange:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: green;
}
.orange:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table data-vertable="ver2">
     <thead>
          <tr>
               <th></th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          <tr class="green">
               <th>hello</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="green">
               <th>text</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="orange">
               <th>random</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="orange">
               <th>value</th>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Rajan, what I want to achieve is for all TRs with class of Green to have alternating colors of green. All TRs with class=orange to alternate colors in orange. Green rows and orange rows won't always necessarily be together, but they must alternate only in the color that I defined. Here's an example: https://i.imgur.com/Cmun9ef.jpg

Comment: @pufAmuf you cannot do that, as simple as that ... Rajan, you logic is somehow wrong even if it works in this particular case

Comment: My logic is based on what I understood from the question and code provided along with that. It may be possible that I could not understand completely what OP wanted to explain.

Comment: the 2n and 2n+1 works on all the element and not the elements with this particular class to be clear ... so if you are aware about this ok, if you think this is working with classes you are wrong

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it that does not require Jquery?

Comment: @TemaniAfif 2n will work on all the even classes  and 2n+1 will work on all the odd classes, right? but what did you mean by `2n and 2n+1 works on all the elements and not the elements with this particular class` please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `2n will work on all the even classes and 2n+1 will work on all the odd classes` --> here you are wrong, it deosn't consider classes, it consier ALL the elements so 2n will work on all the even elements THEN if that element have this class it will apply if not, no

Comment: Alright, so is it not the recommended way to add style like this, because I always use this in my projects.